# Recessing Look Cleats

Tags: pedals, clipless, spd, modification

A lot of SPD shoes (not SPD-SL) have the cleat recessed into the shoe so you can walk with it. Has anyone found a way to get Look Keo cleats to be recessed so they are better for walking?

I suspect this is not easy due to the way they clip in and the only improving walking things you can do are grip cleats and the cleat covers.

Comment: SPD-SL cleats are basically the width of the shoe. Looking at the sole of the shoe its difficult to imagine how the cleat could be recessed to allow walking. My "solution" to this one is to have 2 sets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt you will find a way to do this; it would require a shoe with a pretty deep sole to recess the cleats into (that's what SPDs do).

Note that the SPD-SLs are pretty similar to the Looks but much more walkable.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. I'd probably swap to plain SPD instead, but I'm too cheap to buy new pedals and new shoes.

Comment: Many shoes with a 3-bolt fitting also have a 2-bolt fitting which may be hidden by a 3-bolt cleat.